# Rails BCrypt password checking is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, passwords, bcrypt

I'm using a password system where when the user signs up, a salt is generated for them, using `BCrypt::Password.create("Use #{username} with #{Time.now} and #{rand(100)} to make salt", cost: 13)`.

It then also encrypts their entered password with `BCrypt::Password.create("Put #{salt} on the #{password}")` and then saves both to the database.

When they log in, it uses this:

```
check_password = BCrypt::Password.new(hashed_password)
check_password == "Put #{salt} on the #{password}"
```

The problem is that any password check always returns true, as long as the salt is a BCrypt encrypted string.

I'm fairly new to BCrypt so I may be doing this completely wrong. Is it my technique or a deeper problem?